# Sync master branch with develop

Tags: git, github

I'm a contributor to an open source organization and one of our developers was working with the master branch and wanted to sync master with develop. But due some conflicts and all the history got messed up a bit. I would like to know how can master be restored to it's previous state or the best thing be in synchronization with the develop.

This is the repo for reference

https://github.com/systers/vms

**EDIT1**

Till now, I have tried doing

`git checkout master`

`git reset --hard develop`

This made my master in sync with develop locally but I'm not sure whether it's the best practice to do.

Further, I plan to do

`git push --force origin master`

**EDIT2**

The above solution didn't work as `origin/master` is a protected branch. So, I got this error:

`remote: error: Cannot force-push to a protected branch`

Comment: try to merge that dev branch with your local master and then try to resolve conflicts.

Comment: git checkout master; git reset --hard develop; git push --force.

Comment: Thanks @JB NizetThis is what I did. I would like to know. Is this the best practice?

Comment: The best practice would be to avoid messing up with the history, but since that's what you want to do, then, well, do it. People who have started working from the previous master will hate you, but hey...

Comment: Yeah, so what else can be done? That's what I am more interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so what else can be done? That's what I am more interested in.

An alternative is to create a new commit, mirror copy of an old valid commit.
You can then push that new commit without having to use `--force`.

First, mark the current HEAD of `master`: we need to move that HEAD *without* modifying `master`, so let's create a new temporary branch called '`tmp`' where `master` is.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b tmp
```

Then let's go back to an older commit with the right content.

```
git reset --hard <old_commit>
```

That reset the index (and working tree) to the right content, but that also moves HEAD. Fortunately, that moves `tmp` HEAD, not `master` HEAD.

Now, let's move back `tmp` HEAD to where `master` is, but without modifying the index or the working tree (which are representing what we need for a new commit)

```
git reset --soft master
```

Let's make a new commit, on top of `master`/`tmp` HEAD, which represents the right content (the old commit).

```
git commit -m "new commit, image of an old one"
```

Finally, we force `master` to be where `tmp` is: one new commit later.

```
git branch -M tmp master
git checkout master
```

The idea behind creating a new commit, instead of changing the current history, is that a regular `git push` is enough, and your colleagues can simply pull as usual, and still get the old reset content:

```
git push
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC, Can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: @AbhishekArya Yes, I have added the intermediate step comments.

Comment: Hi @VonC, as I wanted my master branch to be in sync with develop, I did a `git merge develop` after this. But, it says `Already up-to-date`. What do I do?

Comment: @AbhishekArya That can indicate the ancestors of `master` includes the commits from `develop`. Either directly or through a past merge. In both cases, `master` is in sync (plus a few newer commits) with `develop`, so there is nothing to do.

Comment: @AbhishekArya Maybe you need to do a `git pull` on `develop` first, in case other commits were published on remote `origin/develop`. *Then* a merge would be possible.

Comment: I tried doing `git reset --hard old-commit` and then I did a `git merge develop`. Now, my master looks like as I want it to be locally. But the thing is `upstream/master` is 6 commits ahead and when I do `git push upstream master`. It says `Everythhing is up-to-date`

Comment: I also tried doing `git push --force upstream master`. That also leads to the same message

Comment: @AbhishekArya You don't push to upstream. You push to origin. upstream refers to the original repo that was forked.

Comment: And then send a PR?

Comment: I am one of the admins actually

Comment: @AbhishekArya Yes, to the upstream repo.

Comment: @AbhishekArya If you are an admin, then you don't need an "upstream" remote: you clone your repo directly, as "origin".

Comment: Actually, these 6 commits have some messed up stuff that was done by one of the contributors. So, the repo won't be affected, right after this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177965/discussion-between-vonc-and-abhishek-arya).